# droppable in droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I have this markup

```
<ul id="hello" class="cat">
    <ul id="a1" class="cat">
    </ul>
    <ul id="a2" class="cat">
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I did this thing

```
$("ul.cat").droppable(
{
    drop:function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

It always write "hello".
only "hello".
How can I bind droppable on childs too?

UPD: I want drop in elements in #hello's chidlren AND #hello itself. I want to determine where li was dropped.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle example of your code?

Comment: I've fixed html markup. Stackoverflow doesn't show html by default if this is not marked as "code"

Comment: What are inside the ul elements?

Comment: It doesn't matter There will be "li" dragged from other container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution: #hello needs `greedy:true`

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#propagation

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("ul.cat").each(function(){

  $(this).droppable(
  {
      drop:function()
      {
          alert($(this).attr("id"));
      }
  });

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HXjeQ/

Comment: Will still alert "hello" as it bubbles up.

Comment: @rsplak i fixed the html as well

Answer (score 0):

It will bubble up to the top UL, which you don't want droppable. Try this:

```
$("#hello ul.cat").droppable(
{
    drop:function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

[here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmxzn/)

Comment: thank you for fiddle. And what about ul.cat in ul.cat in ul.cat? I want to prevent bubble top

Comment: and i want to drop into #hello